# How to test Touch ID feature while don't have iPhone 5s device

Tags: ios, touch-id

I want to implement touch id feature into an app, for that i have written code:

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {
            [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                    localizedReason:@"Are you the device owner?"
                              reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

                                  if (error) {
                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                      message:@"There was a problem verifying your identity."
                                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                      [alert show];
                                      return;
                                  }

                                  if (success) {
                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                                                      message:@"You are the device owner!"
                                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                      [alert show];

                                  } else {
                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                      message:@"You are not the device owner."
                                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                      [alert show];
                                  }

                              }];

        } else {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Your device cannot authenticate using TouchID."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

        }
```

I don't have devices which support touch id feature, So where i can test it to see its functionality work fine or not.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to find someone with a device with Touch ID who can lend it to you for testing.

Comment: Please format the code correctly, it would be easier for the answerer.

Comment: okk.. i have one question, if run this code in a supported device so what happened after executing this code? is it show another screen or directly identify finger touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only test TouchID on a real device. The simulator does not support this.

Comment: I don't have iPhone 5s. Any other way is there for testing it?

Comment: @user2493047 No, you need a iDevice with TouchID to test it.

Comment: Some iPads also support Touch ID.